# Gcloud script filter syntax not supported in CloudResourceManager SDK

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm working on querying all projects in a GCP organization with an exclusion list of project numbers or folder Ids. As the filter can potentially exclude up to 50K projects, client side filtering is not an option.

Using the Gcloud script, I am able to generate and run the filter correctly, however the REST SDK in C# throws the following error:

`{"The service cloudresourcemanager has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is BadRequest.  field [filter] has issue [contains global restriction]"}`

The filter is generated dynamically based on the [Gcloud topic filter docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters).

See example:

`gcloud projects list --filter="lifecycleState:ACTIVE AND (NOT ((parent.type=folder parent.id=(<folder1>,<folder2>,<folder3>)) OR (id=(<project1>))))"`

The corresponding C# code which throws the error:

```
var projectsListRequest = service.Projects.List();
projectsListRequest.Filter = await GenerateProjectFiltersAsync();
var projects = projectsListRequest.Execute();
```

The value of 'Filter' int he C# code is:

`"lifecycleState:ACTIVE AND (NOT ((parent.type=folder parent.id=(<id1>,<id2>,<id3>)) OR (id=(<id4>))))"`

Are these combined filters not supported in the SDK? if not - is it possible to execute a script command via REST call in the SDK to make up for the diff?

Additionally, the "filter" property on "List" is only available in 'Google.Apis.CloudResourceManager.v1'. Has this option been deprecated in v2/3?

Adding the result of running:
`gcloud projects list --filter="lifecycleState:ACTIVE AND (NOT ((parent.type=folder parent.id=(<id1>, <id2>, <id3>)) OR (id=(<id4>))))" --log-http`

==== request start ====
uri: https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects?alt=json&filter=lifecycleState%3AACTIVE+AND+NOT+%28%28parent.type%3Dfolder+AND+%28+parent.id%3D48653349664+OR+parent.id%3D855697431759+OR+parent.id%3D962793046836+%29%29+OR+id%3D521824619001%29&pageSize=500
method: GET
== headers start ==
b'accept': b'application/json'
b'accept-encoding': b'gzip, deflate'
b'authorization': --- Token Redacted ---
b'content-length': b'0'
b'user-agent': b'google-cloud-sdk gcloud/392.0.0 command/gcloud.projects.list invocation-id/84f69f98bfa247e296b2b6cbee217c61 environment/devshell environment-version/None interactive/True from-script/False python/3.9.2 term/screen (Linux 5.10.109+)'
== headers end ==
== body start ==

Comment: Please include the result of `await GenerateProjectFilterAsync()` in your question or otherwise convince us that it matches the filter that you're providing to `gcloud`.

Comment: [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) is your friend. Here's the API documentation for [Cloud Resource Manager](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/). You can see that v1 [`projects.list`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list) has a `filter` field and v3 [`projects.list`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/list) does not. It has been replaced by [`projects.search`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/search)

Comment: The documentation for [`ProjectsResource.List`](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.CloudResourceManager.v1/latest/api/Google.Apis.CloudResourceManager.v1.ProjectsResource.html#Google_Apis_CloudResourceManager_v1_ProjectsResource_List) explains the transition.

Comment: It's unclear which version of the API Client LIbrary you're using but I assume v1. If so, I suspect that the error is in the return value of `GenerateProjectFilterAsync`. The API Client Libraries are machine-generated and so, while it's possible that they contain errors, it's less likely. They're generated from the discovery documents that's used to produce e.g. APIs Explorer too. All to say that, if `gcloud` (which uses the same endpoints) is working and code using API Client Libraries isn't, it's probably your code that's in error.

Comment: You may also run `gcloud projects list --filter=... --log-http` to see the underlying REST API method(s) used to fulfill the `gcloud` command.  Plus APIs Explorer let's you try|repeat these commands in the browser v3 [`projects.search`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/search) or v1 [`projects.list`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list) see "Try this method"

Comment: Thanks all for the responses! I've updated the original question with more info. 
I've been using the API explorer documentation. 
the filters are both identical, and i can't seem to figure out what this means:

{"The service cloudresourcemanager has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is BadRequest. field [filter] has issue [contains global restriction]"}

I'm getting the same errors executing the exact same filter in API explorer as the gcloud script:

Comment: After comparing the gcloud script with the generated REST one, it seems they are transformed before executing. Isn't this syntax supported? `key=(valueA,valueB,valueC)? lifecycleState:ACTIVE AND (NOT ((parent.type=folder parent.id=(<id1>,<id2>,<id3>)) OR (id=(<id1>)))) ` is translated to `lifecycleState:ACTIVE AND NOT ((parent.type=folder AND ( parent.id=<id1> OR parent.id=<id2> OR parent.id=<id3>)) OR id=<id4>)`

Comment: I agree, it's confusing. As you've shown above, no, `key=(valueA,valueB,...)` is **not** apparently supported by the underlying method. `gcloud` transforms that [topic filter](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) into a union. It's unclear whether this is fully documented or limited to what's shown on the API method's [query parameters](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/search#query-parameters)

Comment: It may be worth raising an issue using Google's public [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) using the [Cloud Resource Manager](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187210&template=1162686) component and asking for definitive documentation. I recall Google was revising filtering and it would be useful to see it documented.

Comment: thanks, opened an Issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239815187

Answer (score 0):

As of now, it appears some filtering capabilities documented officially on [Topic filter documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) are only supported in Gcloud shell and are translated into other filtering commands when calling the REST endpoint.

The easiest way, as suggested above, was to run the working Gcloud command with the `--log-http` flag at the end, then snag and decode the filter used for the actual REST call to see if it was changed.

In my case, the filter `key=(value1,value2,value3)` which should have matched either value, was translated into `key=value1 OR key=value2 OR key=value3`, which worked for me.

in General based on the docs it seems there are some inconsistencies with the expected behavior, however this specific filter did not have any additional info.

I've opened an issue to track this:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239815187